# How do I implement an ArrayList to add "Room" objects to the "House" objects list?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I'm currently doing as assignment where I have two classes Room and House. As part of the assignment I need to enable a house class to store the rooms in an `ArrayList`:

> Implement a method to read in room information in the `House` class from the keyboard — this should call the `Room` constructor as required. Create a zero-argument House constructor to call this new method.

I apologize if this is vague or has been answered elsewhere but having tried to understand the explanations on other similar queries, I don't know how to apply them to my situation.

How do I apply `ArrayList` of a `Room` to the house class?

**`House`:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class House {

private int idNum;
private static int internalCount = 0; 
private ArrayList rooms = new ArrayList();
private String address;
private int numRooms;
private String houseType; 

public House (String address, int numRooms, String houseType) {
idNum = internalCount++;

this.address = address;
this.numRooms = numRooms;
this.houseType = houseType;     
}


public House () {
int i = 0;  
idNum = ++internalCount;

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
scan.useDelimiter("\n");

System.out.println("Enter address of house:");   
address = scan.next();

System.out.println("Enter number of rooms:");   //Number of rooms in the House
numRooms = scan.nextInt();

 while (i < numRooms)  //This will loop until all rooms have been described
 {
 add.room = new Room[100]; //I understand this is incorrect but I don't know what  I should have in here
 i++;
 }

 System.out.println("Enter type of house:");
 houseType = scan.next();
 }
 public void addroom(String description, double length, double width)
 {

 }

 int getIdNum() {
 return idNum;
 }


 @Override

 public String toString()
 {
  String report = "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n";
  report += "Address: " + address + "\n";
  report += "No. of Rooms: " + numRooms + "\n";
  report += "House Type: " + houseType+ "\n";
  report += "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n";

  return report;
 }
 }
```

**`Room`:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Room {

private String description;
private double length;
private double width;

public Room (String description, double length, double width) {
this.description = description;
this.length = length;
this.width = width;     
}

public Room () {
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
scan.useDelimiter("\n");

System.out.println("Enter description of room:");
description = scan.next();

System.out.println("Enter length of room:");
length = scan.nextDouble();

 System.out.println("Enter width of room:");
 width = scan.nextDouble();
 }

 /*
 * Calculates and returns area of Room
 */
 public double getArea () {
 return length*width;
 }


 @Override
 public String toString() {
 return description + "- Length: " + length + "m; Width: " + width + 'm';
 }   
}
```

Comment: Ask a specific question related to arraylist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is homework I wont solve it in entirety but give you a foundation to work from...

```
public class House {
  private List<Room> rooms;

  public House() {
    rooms = new ArrayList<Room>();
  }

  public void addRoom(...) {
    Room room = new Room(...);
    rooms.add(room);
  }

  public int numRooms() {
    return rooms.size();
  }

  public Room getRoom(int roomNumber) {
    return rooms.get(roomNumber);
  }
}

public class Room {
  public Room(...) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Questions?

Comment: Having revisited my problem this was perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for ArrayList ?

You need something like:

```
rooms.add(new Room());
```

Further, I would make use of Java generics and define the list thus:

```
private ArrayList<Room> rooms;
```

This makes use of [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/), and ensures that this can only be a list of rooms, not miscellaneous objects. It will save you some grief in that you can't inadvertently add houses to your list of rooms (through programming errors)

Answer (score 0):

Using specialization the list to the `Room` type

```
List<Room> rooms = new ArrayList<Room>();

while (i < numRooms)  //This will loop until all rooms have been described
{
  rooms.add(new Room()); //this is correct 
  i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks to all of you! Any one of these answers could have cleared this up for me! I just wish I'd asked for help about 5 hours ago. Thanks agian.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Room> rooms = new ArrayList<Room>();
rooms.add(new Room());
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your constructors methods adding some code about your rooms `ArrayList`.

```
public House(..., ArrayList aRooms) {

 ...
 rooms = aRooms;
}

public House() {

 ...
 // It's better to instantiate the rooms array here.
 rooms = new ArrayList<Room>();
}
```

To add rooms to your rooms `ArrayList`, just do something like that (don't forget to check the `ArrayList` API, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

```
ArrayList<Room> rooms = new ArrayList<Room>();
rooms.add(new Room(...));
// Add here all the rooms you need.

House house = new House(rooms);

// You can also create a method into the House class to allow adding new rooms once you have created a House object.
public void addRoom(Room room) {

 this.rooms.add(room);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this loop:

```
while (i < numRooms)  //This will loop until all rooms have been described
{
  add.room = new Room[100]; //I understand this is incorrect but I don't know what I  should have in here
 i++;
}
```

To:

```
while (i < numRooms) 
{
Room newRoom = new Room();
rooms.add(newRoom);
i++;
}
```